# floating point number in iterator

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

i am trying to run an iteration which goes upto a floating point number. Unfortunately, the iteration variable is an integer. i want to know how can fix this problem. here is the code snippet:

```
for it in range(num_iters):
      if it % 10 == 0:  print ('starting iteration ', it)
```

the value for num_iters is floating point. the error i am getting getting is:

```
---> 69     for it in range(num_iters):
     70       if it % 10 == 0:  print ('starting iteration ', it)
     71 

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `range(int(round(num_iters))):`